# Should questions with high views but few upvotes get reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295075/how-can-i-add-new-column-with-new-values-in-it-for-all-rows-in-sql) and thought about a few times I've seen questions that are old like this question and have a few thousand views, but almost no upvotes. Should questions like this get some form of reputation?

I have only been on SE for a few years, but I am really grateful to the awesome people who have been on here answering and asking questions so long and have contributions that have obviously been 'seen', but not upvoted.

Let me add another twist so you understand why this isn't as simple as it seems.
Let's say that the reputation follows a [generalized Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution), so almost all the questions are at zero and then a few ones then, basically zero, are extremely high. A question getting high traffic, but very few upvotes, could possibly be a question "just not being helpful" or alternatively it could be in a complex domain. Alternatively, the community associated with that topic could just be less generous in general. Why would a nine-year-old question have 5 thousand views and appear to have near zero up or down votes?

Is it more likely people learning SQL for the first time were under stress and didn't really appreciate the question or answer enough to even upvote or downvote it, or do we really thing even 1% of the 5000k people even voted at all?

If 1% of people who view questions on Stack Overflow tend to give an upvote on questions and 0.001% on the [Philosophy site](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour), it makes reputation there much more significant.

I perceive there is much more nuance than no-upvote = bad question.

Comment: If a question has had a *lot* of views and not been upvoted much, that suggests to me that not many people found it helpful/useful; I don't see why such questions should therefore get reputation. Seems to me, in my opinion, that the system is working correctly.

Comment: "*I perceive their is much more nuance then no-upvote=bad question.*" and yet all you want is for views to provide rep, regardless of the nuance here? A question that shares keywords with something people are after but *doesn't* help them will also have high views but would have been **un**helpful to them. Why is this nuance just lost in your plea to consider nuance and just blindly award rep?

Comment: high view count but few votes just means that that question most likely contains some very preferable / general terms for SEO to use, which is why it is more visible.

Comment: *"I have only been on SE for a few years"* - it can take over a decade to fully understand Stack Overflow. You're probably still in the denial phase and think Stack Overflow is all about helping people. That is when things such as gratefulness and wanting to apply reputation points as a reward system come into play. The reality is much more neutral.

Comment: If anything, the question could have wasted the time of visitors who were either not logged in or had low reputation, and were unable to downvote it accordingly.

Comment: @VLAZ I thought of that as well but as the general consensus was opposed I didn't feel the need to include it. In that case the appropriate reaction would be to upvote the right answer, and downvote unhelpful or irrelevant posts with good seo.

Comment: E-net4 that's a good point. and @gimby your comment seems very mysterious is it about SE firing mods for "little reason" and trying to get as much free labor as possible?

Comment: Can't speak for Gimby, but to me Stackoverflow isn't about helping people one at a time. It's about creating a repository of high-quality questions and answers that help many people over time. Reputation's nothing more than gamification, the real value of content is in the number of people who acknowledged that the post was useful. The voting system is far from perfect, but it's better than the other stuff that's been tried.

Answer (score 31):

A question with 5k views and only...a grand total of +2/0 **for nearly 10 years**, with the second upvote **only coming in within the last few days** doesn't tell me that a lot of those 5k people found the question that *good*.

Views aren't a measure of helpfulness.  Views are a result of someone hitting a page from Google or Bing and then needing to find more.

So no, I don't think reputation should be awarded here.  This question, while fine, is pretty...meh to future viewers, so it makes sense that someone wouldn't want to upvote it if they passed by it.